# PHP won't create a table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

currently I'm making a forum software, and I'm writing the install script, that sets up the database and tables within it. It makes the database and tables fine. It's supposed to make 4 tables: forums, posts, topics, and user_info.

It successfully makes the databse, forums, posts, and topics, but it doesn't create the user_info table, and I can't figure out why.

Here's my code:

```
$createdb = "CREATE DATABASE forumstest";
$run_createdb = mysql_query("$createdb");

//Create tables
mysql_select_db("forumstest");

$createforums = "CREATE TABLE forums (id int NOT NULL, description text, PRIMARY KEY (id))";
mysql_query("$createforums");

$createposts = "CREATE TABLE posts (id int NOT NULL, created_by varchar(200), date_created date, the_post text, topic_id text, PRIMARY KEY (id))";
mysql_query("$createposts");

$createtopics = "CREATE TABLE topics (id int NOT NULL, title varchar(200), created_by varchar(200), date_created date, forum_id text, PRIMARY KEY (id))";
mysql_query("$createtopics");

$createtopics = "CREATE TABLE user_info (id int NOT NULL, username varchar(25), password varchar(100), name varchar(65), email varchar(65), date date, group text, PRIMARY KEY (id))";
mysql_query("$createtopics");

$dbcreated = 1;
echo "Database created sucessfully!";
```

Comment: Maybe if you added some error checking in your code you might have a better idea why it went wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`date` is, just like `group`, a reserved keyword, which you would have seen if you did some error checking.

Comment: So how do I fix it? Because I still want the date in there. Should I just change the date part of the table to like date_joined?

Comment: [List of reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: @darren - change the column name to something else

Comment: you could try putting date in backticks `date` , but even if that works you'd have to constantly reference this column like that. it's just not a good idea to use reserved words.

Comment: First Google hit on "mysql reserved keyword": [Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html): _"Reserved words are permitted as identifiers if you quote them as described in [Section 8.2, “Schema Object Names”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html)"_.

Comment: remove your field alias "date" and rename your field "date' to something like "post_date"

Comment: Thanks guys, I fixed it. I just changed the date and group columns.

Comment: also why are your foreign keys marked as a 'text' column type?

Comment: `date` is ***not*** a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 2):

`date` and `group` are the mysql reserved word. you must keep them with in backticks or not to use the reserved words as column name at all.

```
`date` date, `group` text
```

you should use `mysql_error()` with the `mysql_query()` to see what error message mysql through.

```
mysql_query("$createtopics") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

Comment: still wouldn't recommend naming a column which is a reserved keyword...

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same variable to create topics and user_info tables

Answer (score 0):

You should use this two lines for creating user_info table:

```
$create_user_info = "CREATE TABLE user_info (id int NOT NULL, username varchar(25), password varchar(100), name varchar(65), email varchar(65), 'date_created' date, 'group_user' text, PRIMARY KEY (id))";
    mysql_query("$create_user_info");
```

//because date and group are reserved keywords